# Traefik conditional TLS Client authentication on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to setup a TLS mutual authentication through Traefik, on a specific Ingress on Kubernetes. Traefik is running with consul as a KV storage engine.

It seems that only an [entrypoint](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/configuration/entrypoints.go#L251) support the option : `tls.clientCA`

Is there any way to override this options at the frontend level?

The goal is to have an SSL entrypoint that support both non-TLS authentication and TLS authentication on a specific frontend.